# Can't get click event in javascript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello, so I have a div with default class `Unlocked`. When I click on it, I remove the class `Unlocked` and change it to `locked` class, and when I click again, go to the old `Unlocked`.

This my js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("Test");

        $(".Unlocked").click(function(){
            console.log("HI2");
            $("#LeftMenu").css('margin-left', '0');
             $("#LockLeftMenu").removeClass("Unlocked");
            $("#LockLeftMenu").addClass("locked");
             $("#lbl_lock").text("UnLock");


        });

  $(".locked").on("click", function (event) {
            console.log("HI");
            $("#lbl_lock").text("Lock");

            $("#LeftMenu").css('margin-left', '-260px');
            $("#LockLeftMenu").removeClass("locked");
            $("#LockLeftMenu").addClass("Unlocked");


        });

    });
```

This my html i need before click,

```
<div id="LeftMenu">
<div id="LockLeftMenu" class="Unlocked">
<label id="lbl_lock">Lock</label>
</div>
```

after click,

```
<div id="LeftMenu" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<div id="LockLeftMenu" class="locked">
<label id="lbl_lock">UnLock</label>
</div>
```

but after click on the old $(.Unlocked) elements, what I see in console.log is only HI2.HI2.HI2...   I can't get to HI the $(.locked).

Comment: can you please add a fiddle. This code doesn't seem wrong to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the anonymous function has been bound to the element at document ready. Removing or adding class to an element will not change "click" event on that element.

I think better create one class like this :

```
<div id="LockLeftMenu" class="Clickable Unlocked">
```

then in javascript :

```
$(".Clickable").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('Unlocked'))
    {
        console.log("HI2");
        $("#LeftMenu").css('margin-left', '0');
        $("#LockLeftMenu").removeClass("Unlocked");
        $("#LockLeftMenu").addClass("locked");
        $("#lbl_lock").text("UnLock");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("HI");
        $("#lbl_lock").text("Lock");

        $("#LeftMenu").css('margin-left', '-260px');
        $("#LockLeftMenu").removeClass("locked");
        $("#LockLeftMenu").addClass("Unlocked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Test");

    $('#LockLeftMenu').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this).toggleClass('Unlocked locked');

        if($this.hasClass('Unlocked')){
            $("#LeftMenu").css('margin-left', '0');
            $("#lbl_lock").text("UnLock");
        } else {
            $("#lbl_lock").text("Lock");
            $("#LeftMenu").css('margin-left', '-260px');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using below code:

```
$('#LockLeftMenu').live('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this).toggleClass('Unlocked locked');

    if($this.hasClass('Unlocked')){
        $("#LeftMenu").css('margin-left', '0');
        $("#lbl_lock").text("UnLock");
    } else {
        $("#lbl_lock").text("Lock");
        $("#LeftMenu").css('margin-left', '-260px');
    }
});
```

That's All hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("Test");

        $(".Unlocked").click(function(){
            if($('#LockLeftMenu').attr('class') === 'Unlocked'){
                 console.log("HI2");
                 $("#LeftMenu").css('margin-left', '0');
                 $("#LockLeftMenu").removeClass("Unlocked");
                 $("#LockLeftMenu").addClass("locked");
                 $("#lbl_lock").text("UnLock");
             }
             else{
                  console.log("HI");
                  $("#lbl_lock").text("Lock"); 
                  $("#LeftMenu").css('margin-left', '-260px');
                  $("#LockLeftMenu").removeClass("locked");
                  $("#LockLeftMenu").addClass("Unlocked");

             }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is run on page load. This means on page load, the `Unlocked` handler is added to all elements that have class `Unlocked` and the `Locked` handler is added to the elements that have class `Locked` **on page load**. However on page load, there is no element with class `Locked`, so your handler is not added to any element.

You can fix the issue by either using a single handler, like said in other responses, or using [jQuery .delegate() method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Test");

    $(document).delegate(".Unlocked", "click", function(){
        // Unlocked stuff there
    });

    $(document).delegate(".locked", "click", function (event) {
        // Locked stuff there
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function for this job:

```
$(document).delegate('.Unlocked', 'click', function () { ... });
$(document).delegate('.locked', 'click', function () { ... });
```

Here's a <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nn5Fh/)**</kbd>.

By the way, -in case you're wondering- your label dissapears because of the negative left margin you're assigning to it.

Comment: @MauricePerry That's true. Use `delegate` if you want backwards compatibility (for jQuery < 1.7).